# Usage of .js.erb for Ajax in Rails 3 (jquery .js vs .js.erb)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two alternatives to implement ajax in a Rails 3 application.

1- Bind the event on the submit using jquery within the file viewaction.js or viewaction.js.coffee and manage the returned json to modify things in the DOM.

2- Use remote=>true tag in Rails and code a file named viewaction.js.erb to make the modifications in the DOM and use class variables loaded in the controller.

- What is the recommended approach in Rails 3?
- What is the Rails way to do it?
- What is the best practice?
- Specific scenarios when one of the alternatives is best than the
  other?
- What is the recommendation for big projects?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prior to Rails 3, adding `:remote => true` would have generated a bunch of inline JavaScript inside the form tag, but with Rails 3 UJS, the only change is the addition of an HTML 5 custom attribute `data-remote=true`. for example:

```
<%= form_for(@post, :remote => true) do |f| %>
```

will generate

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/posts" class="new_post" data-remote="true" id="new_post" method="post">
```

**for now, this is the rails3 approach**. the js function that generates it is under rails.js file.
If you open the **rails.js** file, you will notice several remote handler definitions. The first one handles the case of remote form submission, the second one handles remote links and input fields, the third handles not-remote links that should behave likes form.

from [looking deeper into the code](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js) i found that this file actually perform a jQuery ajax call:

```
ajax: function(options) {
      return $.ajax(options);
    },
```

so **there is no difference** between using `:remote => true` and a regular jQuery ajax call, **rails acts like a wrapper to call the same methods.**

more info [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-unobtrusive-javascript-and-ajax-with-rails-3/), [here](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/) and [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript).

Comment: I understand that there is no difference if you take a deep look. But from the point of view of code clarity, maintainability and best practices what is your opinion?

Comment: as i said in my answer - the rails way to do it is to add :remote=>true. this make the code standard across all rails3 apps

Comment: I have read opinions that say that it fragments the front end logic of the app (having multiple .js.erb). What do you think about that?